# Flutter-Riverpod - how to combine providers to filter on a Stream

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying to follow the example docs on how to combine Providers using Flutter & Riverpod to filter a list of items. The data is coming from Firestore using Streams:

```
final carListProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<Car>>((ref) {
  final carsRepo = ref.watch(carsRepositoryProvider);
  return carsRepo.cars();
});
```

This all works fine and I can render the list of cars no problem. Now I want to give the user the option to filter the list based on color:

```
enum CarColorFilter {
  all,
  red,
  white,
  black,
}

final carListFilter = StateProvider((_) => CarListFilter.all);
```

And then following the docs example, my attempt to combine the providers:

```
final filteredCars = StreamProvider<List<Car>>((ref) {
  final filter = ref.watch(carListFilter);
  final cars = ref.watch(carListProvider); <-- This line throws the error

  switch (filter.state) {
    case CarColorFilter.all:
      return cars;
    case CarColorFilter.red:
      return cars.where(...)

    default:
  }
})
```

On the line declaring the 'cars' variable the editor complains:

> The argument type 'AutoDisposeStreamProvider<List>' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderBase<Object,
> dynamic>'

I think the difference between my use case and the docs is that in the example given the `List<Todo>` is a `StateNotifierProvider` whereas in my case the `List<Car>` is a `StreamProvider`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer in the docs, posting here in case it helps anyone else:

> When using .autoDispose, you may find yourself in a situation where
> your application does not compile with an error similar to:
>
> The argument type 'AutoDisposeProvider' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderBase'
>
> Don't worry! This error is voluntary. It happens because you most
> likely have a bug:
>
> You tried to listen to a provider marked with .autoDispose in a
> provider that is not marked with .autoDispose

Marking the filteredList provider as `autoDispose` resolves the issue.

Comment: also other providers can be autodispose not only StreamProviders. Didn't know that. So i didnt even look at them.